Walmart Integration OAuth 2.0 - One or more params missing
I'm trying to integrate my app with walmart following this link, but It's showing this error message on the login form "one or more parameters are missing".
  public function authorize(Request $request)
  {
    $params = [
      'responseType' => 'code',
      'clientId' => $this->apiKey,
      'redirectUri' => config('walmart.redirect_url'),
      'clientType' => $request->get('clientType'),
      'nonce' => Str::random(10),
      'state' => Str::random(10)
    ];

    return response(['loginUrl' => 'https://login.account.wal-mart.com/authorize?'.http_build_query($params)], 200);
  }

Using this function I'm redirecting the user to the auth page, any idea on what params are missing ?

Have you been able to figure this out? I am having the same problem and it seems to be related to the clientId. I am able to avoid the error and bring up Walmart's branding when using a clientId generated by Walmart. However, those clientIds aren't what I need!
